# Останавливать работу сервиса если запущено определённое приложение

Tags: java, exec, touch

Вообщем ситуация такая: в фоне циклично работает `RepeatingAlarmService`, нужно прекращать его работу на время работы некоего приложения. У меня идея такая, во время работы этого некоего приложения, из него через `exec` делать `busybox touch /data/work` - тем самым при каждом запуске приложения файл work будет обновлять информацию о времени последнего изменения. В то же время в сервисе сделать проверку что если время изменения файла больше, скажем 10 минут то сервис продолжает работу, если меньше то не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста пример такой функции или может есть какие то другие варианты? Код примерно такой:

```
File file = new File("/data/work");
            if (file.exists()) {
            Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified());
            System.out.println("File: "+lastModified);
            }
```

Как сделать сравнение по времени в 10 минут от текущего времени?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю сам на свой вопрос. Всё очень просто:

```
File file = new File("/data/work");
            if (file.exists()) {
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - file.lastModified()) > 450000) {
                System.out.println("файл создан более 7,5 минут назад");
            } else {
                System.out.println("файл создан менее 7,5 минут назад");
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Получить разницу между двумя отметками времени в минутах можно таким образом:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate ofEpochDay = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(lastModifyTime);
long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(date, ofEpochDay);
```

Ну а дальше сравниваете `minutes` с нужным вам значением.